# Basic streams issue: Difficulty sending a string to stdout

Tags: node.js

I'm just starting learning about streams in node. I have a string in memory and I want to put it in a stream that applies a transformation and pipe it through to `process.stdout`. Here is my attempt to do it:

```
var through = require('through');

var stream = through(function write(data) {
    this.push(data.toUpperCase());
});

stream.push('asdf');

stream.pipe(process.stdout);

stream.end();
```

It does not work. When I run the script on the cli via node, nothing is sent to stdout and no errors are thrown. A few questions I have:

1. If you have a value in memory that you want to put into a stream, what is the best way to do it?
2. What is the difference between `push` and `queue`?
3. Does it matter if I call `end()` before or after calling `pipe()`?
4. Is `end()` equivalent to `push(null)`?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you piping to `process.stdout` instead of writing directly to it?

Comment: Good point - looks like my example was too simple. I've updated it to use a transformation in the stream.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the vanilla stream API

```
var Transform = require("stream").Transform;

// create a new Transform stream
var stream = new Transform({
  decodeStrings: false,
  encoding: "ascii"
});

// implement the _transform method
stream._transform = function _transform(str, enc, done) {
  this.push(str.toUpperCase() + "\n";
  done();
};

// connect to stdout
stream.pipe(process.stdout);

// write some stuff to the stream
stream.write("hello!");
stream.write("world!");

// output
// HELLO!
// WORLD!
```

---

Or you can build your own stream constructor. This is really the way the stream API is intended to be used

```
var Transform = require("stream").Transform;

function MyStream() {
  // call Transform constructor with `this` context
  // {decodeStrings: false} keeps data as `string` type instead of `Buffer`
  // {encoding: "ascii"} sets the encoding for our strings
  Transform.call(this, {decodeStrings: false, encoding: "ascii"});

  // our function to do "work"
  function _transform(str, encoding, done) {
    this.push(str.toUpperCase() + "\n");
    done();
  }

  // export our function
  this._transform = _transform;
}

// extend the Transform.prototype to your constructor
MyStream.prototype = Object.create(Transform.prototype, {
  constructor: {
    value: MyStream
  }
});
```

Now use it like this

```
// instantiate
var a = new MyStream();

// pipe to a destination
a.pipe(process.stdout);

// write data
a.write("hello!");
a.write("world!");
```

Output

```
HELLO!
WORLD!
```

---

Some other notes about `.push` vs `.write`.

- `.write(str)` adds data to the writable buffer. It is meant to be called externally. If you think of a stream like a duplex file handle, it's just like `fwrite`, only buffered.
- `.push(str)` adds data to the readable buffer. It is only intended to be called from within our stream.
- `.push(str)` can be called many times. Watch what happens if we change our function to

  ```
  function _transform(str, encoding, done) {
    this.push(str.toUpperCase());
    this.push(str.toUpperCase());
    this.push(str.toUpperCase() + "\n");
    done();
  }
  ```

  Output

  ```
  HELLO!HELLO!HELLO!
  WORLD!WORLD!WORLD!
  ```

Answer (score 2):

First, you want to use `write()`, not `push()`. `write()` puts data in to the stream, `push()` pushes data out of the stream; you only use `push()` when implementing your own `Readable`, `Duplex`, or `Transform` streams.

<s>Second, you'll only want to `write()` data to the stream **after** you've setup the `pipe()` (or added some event listeners). If you write to a stream with nothing wired to the other end, the data you've written will be lost.</s> As @naomik pointed out, this isn't true in general since a `Writable` stream will buffer `write()`s. In your example you do need to `write()` after `pipe()` though. Otherwise, the process will end before writing anything to `STDOUT`. This is possibly due to how the `through` module is implemented, but I don't know that for sure.

So, with that in mind, you can make a couple simple changes to your example to get it to work:

```
var through = require('through');

var stream = through(function write(data) {
    this.push(data.toUpperCase());
});

stream.pipe(process.stdout);

stream.write('asdf');
stream.end();
```

Now, for your questions:

1. The easiest way to get data from memory in to a writable stream is to simply `write()` it, just like we're doing with `stream.wrtie('asdf')` in your example.
2. As far as I know, the stream doesn't have a `queue()` function, did you mean `write()`? Like I said above, `write()` is used to put data in to a stream, `push()` is used to push data out of the stream. Only call `push()` in your owns stream implementations.
3. Only call `end()` **after** all your data has been written to your stream. `end()` basically says: "Ok, I'm done now. Please finish what you're doing and close the stream."
4. `push(null)` is pretty much equivalent to `end()`. That being said, don't call `push(null)` unless you're doing it inside your own stream implementation (as stated above). It's almost always more appropriate to call `end()`.

Comment: "_Second, you'll only want to write() data to the stream after you've setup the pipe() (or added some event listeners). If you write to a stream with nothing wired to the other end, the data you've written will be lost._" This is just not true. `.write` will automatically buffer data until it's ready to be consumed. Once a stream is `.pipe`'d into another, if there is data in the readable buffer, it will be read immediately.

Comment: if you'd like a demonstration of this, take the example in my question and move the `.pipe` line to be *after* the `.write` calls. You'll see that the output remains identical; no data is lost.

Comment: You're right, my mistake. It doesn't work in OPs original example to  `write` before `pipe` though. The process exits before writing anything to `STDOUT`. Maybe an implementation detail of the `through` module?

Comment: That could be the case. I don't use it, so I have no idea. Streams are plenty complicated as-is yet the `through` module claims it is a "simple way to create a ReadableWritable stream that works". I don't see how even more code makes a complicated problem into a simpler one. Once you understand the native stream internals, I don't think it's so bad to work with them directly.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the examples for stream (http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options)

and through (https://www.npmjs.org/package/through)

it doesn't look like you are using your stream correctly... What happens if you use write(...) instead of push(...)?

Comment: In those docs, it has a line: `var readable = getReadableStreamSomehow();` The "somehow" is exactly what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: Using `write` as opposed to `push` doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Have you tested the examples given at these two locations? Can you get them to work, and if so, can you then adapt that to your problem?